# Canon 7D MkII versus SL3

Tags: canon, comparison

After the news about the release of the new entry-level SL3, I got to wondering in which cases would someone go for the twice the price 7DmkII?

As far as I can tell, the 7D can burst faster (10 x 5 fps) and has GPS, but loses or ties with the SL3 in pretty much everything else, and the DIGIC 6 versus 8 might lead to a gigantic difference too.

Am I missing anything in this comparison?

Source: https://www.dpreview.com/products/compare/side-by-side?products=canon_eos7dii&products=canon_eos250d

Edit:
Please note that I'm aware that the 7D is theoretically "better", as in better constructed, better materials, more direct control of the configurations, etc, in line with pro bodies. It is not a generic "old pro vs new consumer" (which is not covered by the suggested QA either), but rather a concrete instantiation of that generic problem, considering those two models.

Comment: Also, some of those specs are a bit ... off. Over 3k AF points? I think not. Canon's spec sheet says 9...

Comment: Both cameras have "over 3K AF points" in Live View with Dual Pixel CMOS AF. Neither does with viewfinder shooting, where it's 65 all cross type vs. 9 (only one cross type).

Comment: For more, please see: [Autofocus points in Mirrorless Cameras](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/75138/15871) Note: DSLRs are "mirrorless cameras" when using Live View.

Comment: I think also relevant: [Better to buy an older high-level camera or newer entry-level camera?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/48100)

Comment: Re: your edit. The reason that we like generic questions on this site is because in a few years time, nobody will care about either the SL3 or the 7D Mark II because neither will be available (new).

Comment: @osullic Except the 7D Mark II is the current "7-series" body at the top of Canon's APS-C lineup.

Comment: @MichaelC Mmm, so what? I'm not quite sure of your point. It doesn't matter if the 7D Mark II is a current model or not; if someone is comparing a 2014 higher-level camera with a 2019 entry-level camera, don't you think that some of the information in the question I linked to is relevant?

Comment: @osullic In general, that question (and the myriad of "should I buy 1D Mark II or 70D?" type of questions we had been getting at the time that it was designed to unify) seems to be more about "Should I buy an advanced pro camera that was replaced in its series 6-8 years ago versus a new entry level camera" than about comparing the current prosumer APS-C camera to a slightly newer entry level model.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The most significant differences are the [massively superior  AF system](https://media.canon-asia.com/shared/live/products/EN/K289AFGuideBook_web.pdf) of the 7D Mark II, the higher [handling speed](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/47733/15871) and increased number of direct controls of the 7D Mark II, the RGB+IR light meter that gives better metering under difficult lighting and enables [EOS iTR AI Servo AF](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/81838/15871) tracking using the dual processors of the EOS 7D Mark II, flicker reduction in the 7D Mark II, and the much higher [build quality](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/104214/15871), robustness, and dust/weather resistance of the 7D Mark II.

Things the EOS 7D Mark II has that the EOS Rebel SL3/250D does not:

- **[Automatic hypersonic sensor cleaning](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/38656/15871)**. The EOS 7D Mark II has it. If you want to clean the sensor of the Rebel SL3/250D you'll need to get your air blower and swabs out.
- **Highly configurable 65 point AF system** with all cross type point with center dual cross type sensitive at f/8 and extra sensitivity at f/2.8 (compared to 9 AF points with a single center AF point sensitive to f/5.6 and extra sensitivity at f/2.8)
- **Autofocus down to EV -3** (vs. limited to EV -0.5)
- **AF assist** with built-in flash
- **Fully capable ISO compliant hot shoe** that can fire non-Canon flashes (The Rebel SL2/250D has a ["crippled" hot shoe](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/103688/15871) with no ISO "fire" contact in the middle and can only be used with Canon E-TTL capable flashes or Canon E-TTL capable triggers)
- **[AFMA](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/106494/15871)** (Autofocus Micro Adjustment)
- **150,000-pixel [RGB+IR metering](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/97045/15871) sensor** EOS iSA System with 252-zone metering (vs. 63-zone dual layer "monochrome" meter)
- **[Flicker Reduction](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/71226/15871)** for shooting action under flickering light sources, such as stadiums and gyms
- **1.8% and 6% spot/partial metering** (vs. 4% and 9%) allows tighter control of spot metering
- **Metering range** of EV 0 - EV 20 (vs. EV 1 - EV 20)
- **[2, 3, 5, or 7 shot AEB](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/75813/15871)** (vs. 3 shot)
- **1/8000 second** [minimum shutter time](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/43663/15871) (vs. 1/4000)
- **ISO in 1/2 or 1/3 stop increments** (vs. whole stop increments only)
- **Larger, brighter, 22mm eye relief, pentaprism viewfinder** with 1.0X magnification of 100% coverage for an apparent viewfinder image size of 22.4 x 15 millimeters  (vs. smaller, dimmer, 19mm eye relief, pentamirror viewfinder with 0.87X magnification of 95% coverage for an apparent viewfinder image size of 18.43 x 12.315 millimeters)
- **Dual DiG!C 6 processors** (vs. single DiG!C 8 processor)
- **Interchangeable [focusing screen](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/46876/15871)** (2 types: 1 included with camera, 1 available for optional purchase) 1: Standard Focusing Screen Eh-A 2: Super Precision Matte Eh-S Focusing Screen (vs. fixed standard focusing screen)
- **Motor Driven Quick-return mirror** (vs. spring return)
- **More user selected information** available in the viewfinder
- **More direct external controls**, including things such as dedicated 'Depth of Field', AF-ON, Multi-Fn, function buttons, and two control wheels
- **Second LCD information screen** [on top of camera](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/3462/15871)
- **Dual Axis electronic level** in either the viewfinder or on the rear LCD screen
- **More modes with Built-in flash**: E-TTL, Manual, Multi, and Canon optical wireless transmitter (vs. Auto or manual)
- **Wireless multi flash support**
- **Bulb mode and three user configurable Custom exposure modes** (vs. a bunch of non-configurable "Scene" modes)
- **In-camera raw image processing and resizing of both raw and JPEG images** (vs. no in-camera raw processing and resizing of JPEG images only)
- **Multiple Exposures**
- **[Silent](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/38823/15871) single shooting, Silent continuous shooting**
- **Max. Approx. 10 fps** maintained for up to an infinite number of JPEGs or 31 RAW images with UDMA-7 card (vs. Max. Approx. 5 fps maintained for up to unlimited JPEG images or 10 raw images with UHS-I card)
- **55 milliseconds shutter lag** (vs. 75 milliseconds)
- **More image storage options**: JPEG Fine or Normal, RAW, M-RAW, S-RAW (vs. JPEG or RAW)
- **Built-in GPS**
- **More robust construction** with better dust/weather sealing with Magnesium Alloy body (vs. Polycarbonate resin with glass fiber and special conductive fiber)
- **USB 3.0** (vs. Hi-Speed USB)
- **Uncompressed YCbCr 4:2:2, 8-bit video output** with HDMI sound output, Headphone socket
- **Two memory card slots** (UDMA-7 capable CF + UHS-1 SD/SDHC/SDXC) vs. single UHS-1 SD/SDHC/SDXC card slot
- **Wired and IR remote ports** (vs. Bluetooth remote receiver)

Things the EOS Rebel Sl3/250D has that the EOS 7D Mark II does not:

- **Slightly higher resolution** (24.1MP vs. 20.2MP)
- **Two-thirds stop higher native ISO** (25600 vs 16000) but no 1/2 or 1/3 stop ISO settings and the same extended ISO of 51200.
- **Vari-Angle touchscreen** (with equal resolution and size to the fixed rear LCD screen on the 7D Mark II)
- **In-camera creative filters**
- **Cropped 4K 23.98/25 fps video and 29.97/25 fps time lapse recording** plus all of the video size/frame rates offered by the 7D Mark II
- **Built in WiFi, Bluetooth** (vs. the W1-E WiFi Adapter that fits in the SD card slot now supplied with all new 7D Mark II cameras - it's $40 if you have to buy it for a 7DII that was bought without it)

Other than that, there's not much difference between the two.

Comment: Wait, they make interchangeable lens cameras without automatic sensor dust mitigation in 2019? Wow.

Comment: Yep, and they sell some of them [for $260 with a kit lens](https://express.google.com/u/0/product/9964335416831221795_468737166018372310_117072071) after the price settles down. I'm more offended by the lack of a center ISO pin on the flash hot shoe.

Comment: PS I'm voting this up especially for "other than that..."